# Счетчик дубликатов в БД

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy, group-by, flask-sqlalchemy

У меня есть бд

где только одно поле (*title*)
Например:

**title**

*first*

*second*

*first*

Мне нужно подсчитать сколько раз встречается в бд то или иное название. В этом примере мне нужно будет вывести *first* - 2 *second* - 1

Как такое реализовать через [sqlAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Нужен запрос GROUP BY, [документация](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#counting):

```
from sqlalchemy import func
session.query(MyTable.title, func.count(MyTable.title)).group_by(MyTable.title).all()
```

Comment: А как же PEP8, умер?